# How do I show daily computer usage (in minutes) in the indicator panel?

Tags: indicator

I've been searching for something that does this for a while, i.e. if you've used the computer for 2 hours today, it will show 120 minutes in the indicator panel. And then it would reset daily.

If not, any pointers on how I could create something like myself?

Answer (score 0):

"Creating it yourself" is easy if you drop the "indicator panel" requirement...

Otherwise, you'll have to start programming...

So the easy part: Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `uptime | cut --characters=14-18` and you'll see the time in hours since the computer was last booted.  If you turn on your machine every day, it will give you your exact computer usage using this simple procedure...

(And if you've typed it once, pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> brings it back)

Comment: I managed it in Python, will post it as an answer when I've cleaned it up.

Comment: Drop me a comment into this answer after you've posted it, so I can delete my answer then!  ;-)